# Rishi, Chandas and Devatha of Panchakshari Mantra according to Krishna Yajurveda Taittiriya Samhita?

Tags: shiva, mantras, yajur-veda

According to Shukla Yajurveda Madhyandina Shakha (Samhitha), the Rishi of Panchakshari Mantra is Vamadeva, Chandas is Pankti and Devatha is Sadashiva or Rudra.

Who is the Rishi and what Chandas is according to Krishna Yajurveda Taittiriya Shakha (Samhita)?  Kindly provide the source as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Svadhyaya Mandala Pune version of the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́  the r̥ṣi of TS 4.5 (Rudrādhyaya) is Agni-r̥ṣi. The metre is ṣatpadājagatī. The  dēvata is not given.

[image]

[image]

Do note though that the Tāittirīya Anu-krámaṇī is not actually part of the saṁhitā́, so we don't have to take what it says word-for-word. There are instances where anu-krámaṇī-s actually contradict the Véda.

In my opinion I would take what's given in the Vājasaneya-Mā́dhyaṁdina-saṁhitā́-anu-krámaṇī over what the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́-anu-krámaṇī says.

Over 719 mantra-s of the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ are from the Şākala-saṁhitā́, Tāittirīya tradition ascribes them to the dēva-s Prajāpati,  Sōma, Agni and the Viśvēdēva-s where as the Şākala-saṁhitā́-anu-krámaṇī ascribes them to various r̥ṣi-s. In that case also I'd take the r̥ṣi-s ascribed to the Şākala-saṁhitā́-anu-krámaṇī over what the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́-anu-krámaṇī says.

Hence I'd say the Vājasaneya-Mā́dhyaṁdina listing is better and that the actual r̥ṣi is Vāmadēva Gautama, where as I'd stick with the metre listing given by the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́-anu-krámaṇī.

References:

https://archive.org/details/TaittiriyaSamhita1957SvadhyayaMandalPune

Comment: Thank you very much!